# Вопросы про PHP, его класс TCPDF и XML, точнее SVG

Tags: xml, pdf, tcpdf, php, svg

Привет всем. После вчерашних изменений в [проекте](http://vv.vipvizitka.in.ua/po/index2.html), стала задача сохранять не только **лицевую сторону визитки**, но также и **обратную сторону визитки**, при нажатии на кнопку *"Сохранить визитку"* внизу страницы. Затем из двух сохраненных `SVG` изображений (лицевой и обратной стороны визитки) буду генерировать двух страничный `PDF` файл, на стороне сервера, при помощи класса `TCPDF` для `PHP`. Но для этого мне потребуется добавить еще одно поле `textarea`, чтобы туда вносились данные обратной стороны визитки, что будет смотреться вообще не эстетично.

Вопросы:

1. Могу ли я убрать `textarea`, который сейчас находится на [сайте-прототипе](http://vv.vipvizitka.in.ua/po/index2.html) и вместо него добавить два `input` со значениями `hidden`, добавлять в них данные `XML` (`SVG`) - лицевой стороны визитки и обратной стороны визитки, и отправлять на сервер для сохранения в векторные изображения с расширением `SVG`?
2. Поддерживает ли класс `TCPDF` добавление страниц при генерации `PDF` документов, автоматически, с помощью `PHP`?

Надеюсь, я ясно выразил свои мысли и Вы сможете понять, что я имел ввиду ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос можно - закрывать, я уже все реализовал!

1) Да, это можно делать, без проблем.

2) Да, поддерживает,

```
// Добавляем еще одну страницу
    $pdf->AddPage('P', 'A4');
```